# How to send JSON body with curl to Postgrest

Tags: bash, curl, cygwin, postgrest

I'm trying to insert data on my Postgresql DB but I failed.

So basically I can select the data with the query below;

```
curl 10.127.18.18:3001/mytable
```

I can get all rows with this request.

I tried pretty much combination of the commands below but all of them failed. How can I insert a basic data with postgREST?

"**mytable**" table has 2 columns, "**user_id**" and "**username**";

```
curl POST 10.127.18.18:3001/mytable { "user_id": 3333, "username": testuser }
curl -X POST 10.127.18.18:3001/mytable HTTP/1.1 { "user_id": "3333", "username": "testuser" }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should work [just like that](https://postgrest.org/en/v3.2/api_writing.html). What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you escape the http body as a string literal in the shell?

Comment: Yes, I tried withoud HTTP body but still same "curl -X POST 10.127.17.72:3000/test1  { "user_id": "3333", "username": "testuser" }".  Error is : curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}
 ^

Comment: That's not a postgres(t) error at all, but a curl usage error. What shell are you using?

Comment: cygwin on windows. Even if I try on Ubuntu, I get similar errors.  {"message":"Error in $: not enough input"}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: user_id; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 3333,; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: username; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: testuser; Unknown error

Answer (score 2):

For those who encounter with the same problem, this query worked for me;

```
curl --location --request POST '10.127.18.18:3001/mytable' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{  "user_id": "11", "username": "test"  }'
```